# Having issues with dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm writing a report that needs to collect data each day, between 0900hs and 1700hs.
I thought it would be fine as follows:

```html
cast(convert(char(8),t.trxtime,112)as time)
 between  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108) >= '09:00' 
  and CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108) < '17:00'
```

....BUT no cigar.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What are the results you expect?

Comment: Read up on datepart and the related date/time manipulation functions in Books Online [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc514207.aspx].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, you could just use `datepart()`:

```
where datepart(hour, t.trxtime) between 9 and 16 and
      cast(t.trxtime as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

I'm not sure if the date comparison is actually necessary.

Comment: Thank you Gordon,  I modified the date comparison and it worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (assuming you mean actually for the current date, and not for *every* date in a range:

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

select @startDate = '2014-11-03 09:00:00',
 @endDate = '2014-11-03 17:00:00'

select *
from table
where myDate between @startDate and @endDate
```

if you did mean between 0900 and 1700 for each day, you could do:

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

select @startDate = '2014-10-03',
 @endDate = '2014-11-03' -- note i'm still limiting it to a range of ~1 month

select *
from table
where myDate between @startDate and @endDate
   and datepart(hour, myDate) between 9 and 17
```

Comment: Thank you!!! your last select stament worked. something similar also suggested by Gordon Linoff above! You guys are an amazing crowd!